# Tensorflow dataset with changing batch size to compute test loss during training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run a training loop where I periodically determine the current average loss and print it to the console. In order to determine the loss I'd like to use a different batch size. So it goes like this:

```
dataset = create_dataset().shuffle(1000).repeat().batch(minibatch_size)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator() # using this iterator in the graph

while ...:
 session.run(...) # perform training

 if epoch % 10 = 0:
  test_avg_loss = session.run(avg_loss) # want a different number of items here
```

I want a minibatch size of 10 during training but I'd like to test with 100 data points to obtain a better estimate for the average loss. How can make the dataset return a different number of items here? I tried passing a `placeholder` to `batch` but it seems unsupported. The error is:

> 'ValueError : Cannot capture a placeholder (name:batchSize, type:Placeholder) by value.'

I'm open to using a different code structure altogether if that seems like a better solution. I understand it is important to not pass data using `feedDict` for performance reasons so using a `dataset` seems like the way to go. I'm not seeking some kind of hack but I'd like to know what's the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is to use a reinitializable iterator, that let you switch between two (or more) `Dataset`s, typically one for training and one for validation.

[The example in the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator) is actually pretty neat:

```
# Define training and validation datasets with the same structure.
training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(100).map(
    lambda x: x + tf.random_uniform([], -10, 10, tf.int64))
validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(50)

# A reinitializable iterator is defined by its structure. We could use the
# `output_types` and `output_shapes` properties of either `training_dataset`
# or `validation_dataset` here, because they are compatible.
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(training_dataset.output_types,
                                           training_dataset.output_shapes)
next_element = iterator.get_next()

training_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(training_dataset)
validation_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(validation_dataset)

# Run 20 epochs in which the training dataset is traversed, followed by the
# validation dataset.
for _ in range(20):
  # Initialize an iterator over the training dataset.
  sess.run(training_init_op)
  for _ in range(100):
    sess.run(next_element)

  # Initialize an iterator over the validation dataset.
  sess.run(validation_init_op)
  for _ in range(50):
    sess.run(next_element)
```

Just make sure in your case that the iterator you create has an unknown batch size.

Comment: I see! What kind of performance cost comes with reinitialization? Is this viable? I imagine the initialization might need to copy data to the GPU and reshuffle it.

Comment: The cost is more a memory one, since you will typically buffer for both Datasets. Switching per se is virtually costless I would say.

Comment: That would be ideal. I'm going to wait a bit for other answers but this one seems very good.

Comment: I just benchmarked each run call. It turns out that the cost of the initializations rises with the number of elements specified in `shuffle`. Both the init op as well as the first test/train run call after the initialization become more costly. So it's not a constant time switch. The costs are low enough for my purposes, though.

Comment: Didn't know that. Does it mean buffers are dropped when switching? That would make me sad.

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe this could be avoided if it was possible to transform `if (placeholderIsTesting) return test.next(); else return train.next();` to a tensorflow op. That would leave both streams initialized. It's strange that the official documentation is so silent on this critical issue. Any real world training pipeline has to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you should look into a `feedable iterator` that can be used together with `tf.placeholder` to select what Iterator to use in each call to tf.Session.run, via the familiar feed_dict mechanism. It offers the same functionality as a `reinitializable iterator`, but it does not require you to initialize the iterator from the start of a dataset when you switch between iterators.

```
# Training and validation datasets
training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(100).repeat().batch(100)
validation_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(150, 200).repeat().batch(10)

# A feedable iterator to toggle between validation and training dataset
handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(
handle, training_dataset.output_types, training_dataset.output_shapes)
next_element = iterator.get_next()

training_iterator = training_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
validation_iterator = validation_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:

   # The `Iterator.string_handle()` method returns a tensor that can be evaluated
   # and used to feed the `handle` placeholder.
   training_handle = sess.run(training_iterator.string_handle())
   validation_handle = sess.run(validation_iterator.string_handle())

   # Run 20 epochs in which the training dataset is traversed, followed by the
   # validation dataset.
   for _ in range(20):
      for _ in range(100):
        out = sess.run(next_element, feed_dict={handle: training_handle})

      for _ in range(50):
        out = sess.run(next_element, feed_dict={handle: validation_handle})
```

Comment: That looks like it would perform best. I will look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Shape your placeholder with [None, None]

Now during evaluate and training  do something like this :

Give a structure to your training file :

```
import tensorflow as tf


def shape(dataset):

    #shape your data here 
    return {'input':np.array(input_data),'label':np.array(labels)}


def evaluate(model,batch_size=100):
    sess = tf.get_default_graph()
    iteration = len(dataset) // batch_size

    loss = []

    for j in iteration:
        dataset = dataset[j * batch_size:(j + 1) * batch_size]

        #shape it here before feeding to network 
        dataset=shape(dataset)

        out = sess.run(model, feed_dict={input_place: dataset['input'], labels: data['labels']})
        loss.append(out['loss'])

    return np.mean(loss)

def train(model,batch_size=10):



    iteration=len(dataset)//batch_size

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        for i in epoch(epoch):
            for j in iteration:
                dataset = dataset[j * batch_size:(j + 1) * batch_size]

                dataset = shape(dataset)

                # shape it here before feeding to network 


                out = sess.run(model, feed_dict={input_place: dataset['input'], labels: data['labels']})

            print(out['loss'], out['training_accuracy'])

        print(evaluate(model))
```

Comment: Trying to understand the code... Does this not pass the data through feedDict? I understand that this carries an extremely high performance cost. Note that I'm using `tensorflow.data.dataset` so that I don't have to pass any data through the feedDict right now. If I could send the data through feedDict the problem would be easy to solve.

Comment: It's passing data through feeddict.

Comment: I did not measure it but from what I hear that approach is impossible if you care about performance. You have to construct the graph so that the graph itself performs the data feeding. `dataset` does that.

Comment: @boot4life can you provide any source , I want to read more about it.

Comment: This seems to be a well known article about it: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dataset-in-tensorflow-c758ef9e4428